# Какие есть способы работы с FTP в iOS?

Tags: ftp, swift4

Есть приложение написанное на Swift. Задача состоит в том, чтобы загружать видео на ftp сервер, а так же выгружать оттуда. 
Какие есть способы для этого ?

Answer (score 0):

Для загрузки видео, я использовал STFTPNetwork. Правда он написан на Objective-C, но подружить его со Swift можно.

https://cocoapods.org/pods/STFTPNetwork

Для Swift можно использовать FileProvider
https://github.com/amosavian/FileProvider